# Inkscape: joining arcs and curves

Tags: inkscape, svg

I saw a similar question answered about 10 years ago. But I can't get it to work. I want to join an elliptic arc to a bezier curve so they are a single path. I know SVG supports this. I want to use the "joint selected nodes" command. But when I try to select the two ends they don't seem to be of the same "type" (see image) and I can't select them both.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you can find it again it would be good if you linked the old question/answer here.

Comment: SVG supports paths that combine Bezier and elliptical sections, but Inkscape does not (paths are Bezier only). Maybe you should convert your ellipse to a path in order to join both curves.